# What is the negation of the sentence "$x$ and $y$ have chatted over the Internet"?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I want to know the negation of the following sentence.

> "$x$ and $y$ have chatted over the Internet".

I thought the negation of this is that "$x$ and $y$ have not chatted over the Internet" and understood that $x,y$ have not chatted each other and It doesn't mean $x$ and $y$ have not chatted in their lifetime.

Am I right? Sorry for poor English.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the negation is "$x$ and $y$ have not chatted over the Internet".

I'm not sure what you're getting at with "It doesn't mean $x$ and $y$ have not chatted in their life time".  The sentence says nothing about whether they  have chatted in any other way than over the Internet (e.g. in person).